# Redirecting page back to index.php after login

Tags: php, html, authentication

The problem I encounter is after I log in it goes back to index.php and have to log in again. I should see logout button, not log in button. Regarding customerindex.php, it does not actually exist but i created the page so that i could see logout button (and actually log out). I plan to delete customerindex.php and just use index.php instead.

validate2.php

```
<?php include("connection.php");
//get data from login form
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

//select all data by using email and password entered
$customers = mysql_query("select * from customer where CustomerEmail='".$email."' and CustomerPassword='".$password."'");
$customer = mysql_num_rows($customers);

$managers = mysql_query("select * from manager where ManagerEmail='".$email."' and ManagerPassword='".$password."'");
$manager = mysql_num_rows($managers);

//if customer is true
if($customer== 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers);
    $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
    $name = $row['CustomerName'];

    //start session
    session_start();
    //create session
    $_SESSION['CustomerEmail'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['CustomerName'] = $name;

    //redirect page to customerindex.php    
    header("Location: customerindex.php");
    }
//if manager is true
else if($manager == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($managers);
    $email = $row['ManagerEmail'];
    $name = $row['ManagerName'];

    //start session
    session_start();
    //create session
    $_SESSION['ManagerEmail'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['ManagerName'] = $name;

    //redirect page to managerCP.php
    header("Location: managercp.php");
    }
//if both condition are false   
else    {
    //alert will be appeared
    header("Location: index.php?login=Wrong username or password"); 
}
?>
```

html

```
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="validate2.php" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>
                    <label class="grey" for="log">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="log" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="pwd" size="23" />
                    <label><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                    <a class="lost-pwd" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="validate2.php" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>             
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="password" id="email" size="23" placeholder="password" />
                    <label>A password will be e-mailed to you.</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Log In | Register</a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
```

The code below shows logout button and redirects customer to customerindex.php (But I want them to be redirected to index.php)

```
<div class="tab">
    <ul class="login">
        <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Hello <?php echo $customername ?>!</li>
        <li class="sep">|</li>
        <li id="toggle">
            <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>            
        </li>
        <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul> 
</div> <!-- / top -->
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["email"]);
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Can you link the file `logout.php` or describe what you do?

Comment: is the php code above in validate2.php and logout.php?

Comment: @AnotherGuy i just edited my post

Comment: If `validate2.php` is the php file that handles login, then when you are logging out you are deleting a session variable that does not exist. Then if you elsewhere have checks to see if the use is currently logged in and redirect them, they would get redirected back. That could explain your logout issue.

Comment: Another thing. From what I can see in `validate2.php` you are storing password in plain text. This is a major security issue. If an attacker gets access to your database he would be able to read all the passwords, usernames and emails and use them not only on your site but maybe elsewhere.

Comment: Do you mind correcting the code for me? I don't really understand what you said. I'm sorry. @AnotherGuy

Comment: I just edited my post@Pwner

Comment: As far as storing passwords it is a bit out of topic here so I will  give you some links to useful resources: 

[Keeping passwords safe](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe--net-17577),
[Working with sensitive data](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/best-practices-when-working-with-sensitive-data-securing-your-application--cms-21719) and 
[OWASP - Passwords storage cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: This question is a little bit unclear. How can it go to `customerindex.php` when you're using `header("Location:index.php");` You're either not telling us an important piece of information, or you don't understand the code at all.

Comment: So is there anything I should add/delete in validate2.php? @AnotherGuy I'm not talking about storing passwords btw. It's about login

Comment: Do you have a script in `index.php` that checks if the use is logged in and redirect them if they are?

Comment: So you want to use `index.php` for customers and managers, right?

Comment: The problem I encounter is after I log in it goes back to index.php and have to log in again. I should see logout button, not log in button. Regarding customerindex.php, it does not actually exist but i created the page so that i could see logout button (and actually log out). I plan to delete customerindex.php and just use index.php instead @Luka hope you get what i'm trying to say here

Comment: yes <form action="validate2.php" method="post"> is this what you're talking about? @AnotherGuy

Comment: I am talking about some PHP code that run before the page is shown.

Comment: I don't think I have it, no @AnotherGuy

Comment: Hmn, then this is weird :D

Comment: @Samyo: I get it now. In that case, you're missing some conditional clauses inside your HTML template. Please edit your question so that people don't have to read comments to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> Change this code & see it's working or not..

```
if($customer == 1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($customers)){
        $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
        $name = $row['CustomerName'];
    }
    //start session
    session_start();
    //create session
    $_SESSION['CustomerEmail'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['CustomerName'] = $name;

    //redirect page to customerindex.php    
    header("Location: customerindex.php");
    }
//if manager is true
else if($manager == 1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($managers)){
        $email = $row['ManagerEmail'];
        $name = $row['ManagerName'];
    }
    //start session
    session_start();
    //create session
    $_SESSION['ManagerEmail'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['ManagerName'] = $name;

    //redirect page to managerCP.php
    header("Location: managercp.php");
    }
//if both condition are false   
else    {
    //alert will be appeared
    header("Location: index.php?login=Wrong username or password"); 
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work. Luka was right. I'm missing conditional clauses in html. I don't know what to add/write in html besides    <?php else{}?>     It should get redirected back to index.php and user should be able to see logout button after successfully logging in. Please help me

Answer (score -1):

Use `../` instead of index.php to get redirected to index.php

Comment: It can be deduced that the problem isn't in wrong file path since the OP hasn't told us anything about the `404` error.

Answer (score -3):

Add exit after header.like below.

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

Comment: adding exit won't help

Comment: @SameerShaikh you're correct, it won't solve the problem, but you should exit after a redirect

Comment: I agree, adding `exit` won't help here, but it's a good practice to stop unnecessary code execution (if it really is unnecessary).

Comment: But login button is still there. User should see logout button after logging in @SameerShaikh

Comment: because when ever use header location at that time output should not start before and always add exit after header so it will stop next code execution.